# Is there a background to the phrase 「熊出来てる」?

Tags: meaning

I was watching a TV drama, and one line was:

「熊出来てる」

I would translate it as "seems like a bear is coming out". In context, it seems to refer to a person who has rings under their eyes, due to not getting enough sleep, working too late into the night, etc.

But I am wondering how a bear relates to the meaning of this phrase. Thought I would ask at the risk of it being too narrow a topic.

Comment: http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%9B%AE%E3%81%AE%E9%9A%88

Comment: @snailboat I see. I was thinking there was some hidden meaning. But it was only my bad translation...

Comment: Did it really use the kanji `熊`?

Comment: @syockit It was based on what I heard, くま. I should have checked further to get the correct meaning.

Answer (score 5):

Don't know why snailboat didn't answer the question, but just to make an answer:

くま can also be 隈, which is the dark circles under your eyes when you are tired or don't get enough sleep, like when you have to do lots of overtime at work...